# System.reactive - dynamically switch by frequency

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have two sources of data.

Lets imagine that:

- **System A** provides better quality data with higher frequency e.g.
  1price/1sec, but sometimes has failures and there is no data or
  frequency is e.g 1price/20sec
- **System B** provides data with lower frequency e.g. 1price/10sec

Is there any elegant way using **system.reactive** to normally retrieve data from system A but when it fails (no data in feed) or slows down, to use data from system B?
I want to implement some kind of switch which will use A source when it is faster than B. I don't want to mix sources, so I can use only SystemA or SystemB at once.

```cs
    class PriceFeed {

        public IObservable<Price> GetPricesFeed(IObservable<PriceFromA> pricesFromA, IObservable<PriceFromB> pricesFromB)
        {


        }


        private Price Convert(PriceFromA price) { //convert }

        private Price Convert(PriceFromB price) { //convert }

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting problem. First thing to do would be to write some sort of frequency gathering function. That could look like this:

```
public static IObservable<int> GetFrequency<T>(this IObservable<T> source, TimeSpan measuringFreq, TimeSpan lookback)
{
    return source.GetFrequency(measuringFreq, lookback, Scheduler.Default);
}

public static IObservable<int> GetFrequency<T>(this IObservable<T> source, TimeSpan measuringFreq, TimeSpan lookback, IScheduler scheduler)
{
    return source.Buffer(lookback, measuringFreq, scheduler)
        .Select(l => l.Count);
}
```

If `measuringFreq` is 1 second, and `lookback` is 5 seconds, that means that every second we will see the count of how many messages were delivered in the last 5 seconds. Quick and dirty example:

```
var r = new System.Random();
var nums = Observable.Generate(
    0, 
    i => i < 100, 
    i => i + 1, 
    i => i, _ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(r.NextDouble() * 1)
);
var freq = nums.GetFrequency(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
freq.Dump(); //Linqpad
```

`nums` is an observable that should generate a message on average every half a second (it picks a duration randomly between 0 and 1 seconds). The `freq` produces a value every second which returns the number of messages `nums` produced in the last 5 seconds (which should average 10). On the latest run on my machine, I get this:

```
11
11
12
10
12
11
9
9
10
9
8
...
```

Once we have a way to get the frequency, you need to write a function to synthesize two like-typed observables together, switching based on frequency. I wrote this:

```
public static IObservable<T> MaintainFrequencyImproper<T>(this IObservable<T> sourceA, IObservable<T> sourceB, TimeSpan measuringFreq, TimeSpan lookback, IScheduler scheduler, int aAdvantage = 0)
{
    var aFreq = sourceA.GetFrequency(measuringFreq, lookback, scheduler);
    var bFreq = sourceB.GetFrequency(measuringFreq, lookback, scheduler);

    var toReturn = aFreq.Zip(bFreq, (a, b) => a + aAdvantage - b)
        .Select(freqDifference => freqDifference < 0 ? sourceB : sourceA)   //If advantage is 0, and a & b both popped out 5 messages in the last second, then A wins
        .StartWith(sourceA)
        .Switch();

    return toReturn;
}
```

First we get the frequency with `GetFrequency` for both observables, then we zip those two together, and compare them. If B is more frequent than A, then use B. If they are equivalently frequent or A is more frequent, then use A.

The `aAdvantage` variable allows you to express a stronger preference for A over B. 0 (the default) means that source A wins a tie, or when it is more frequent, but otherwise B wins. 2 would mean that B would have to produce 3 more messages than A in the most recent period to require use of B.

With proper `Publishing` of observables to avoid multiple subscriptions, that would look like this:

```
public static IObservable<T> MaintainFrequencyProper<T>(this IObservable<T> sourceA, IObservable<T> sourceB, TimeSpan measuringFreq, TimeSpan lookback, 
    IScheduler scheduler, int aAdvantage = 0)
{
    return sourceA.Publish(_sourceA => sourceB.Publish(_sourceB => 
        _sourceA.GetFrequency(measuringFreq, lookback, scheduler)
            .Zip(_sourceB.GetFrequency(measuringFreq, lookback, scheduler), (a, b) => a + aAdvantage - b)
            .Select(freqDifference => freqDifference < 0 ? _sourceB : _sourceA)
            .StartWith(_sourceA)
            .Switch()

    ))
}
```

I hope this helps. You didn't leave much in terms of how to fit this into your code. If you want that, then please include a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Nice. What about CombineLatest() instead of Zip()? I think another aspect is that a timeout should be detected earlier than the slower frequency drop

Comment: CombineLatest would introduce race condition issues for combining the two frequency observables. Since they’re essentially on the same timer, I don’t see the point.

Comment: As for timeout, if you set your measuring frequency to be shorter than the timeout duration, it will be faster than a timeout detection system, not slower.

Comment: Update: I realized `GetFrequency` could use `Buffer` instead of `Scan` which is simpler. I changed code accordingly.